# Dynamically create destination table from source server with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, etl, dynamically-generated, db2-400, ssis-2008

I need a bit advice how to solve the following task:

I got a source system based on IBM DB2 (IBMDA400) which has a lot of tables that changes rapidly and daily in structure. I must load specified tables from the DB2 into a MSSQL 2008 R2 Server. Therefore i thought using SSIS is the best choice.

My first attempt was just to add both datasources, drop all tables in MSSQL and recreate them with a "Select * Into @Table From @Table". But I was not able to get this working because I could not connect both OLEDB Connections. I also tried this with an Openrowset statement but the SQL Server does not allow that for security reasons and I am not allowed to change that.

My second try was to manually read the tables from the source and drop and recreate the tables with a for each loop and then load the data via the Data Flow Task. But I got stuck on getting the meta data from the Execute SQL Task... so i dont got the column names and types.

I can not believe that this is too hard to archieve. Why is there no "create table if not exist" checkbox on the Data Flow Task?

Of course i searched for the problem here before but could not find a solution.

Thanks in advance,
Pad

Comment: Well you can check if a table exists in a SQL script by selecting from sys.objects and drop if it is there. It all sounds like a DBA's nightmare though. How will you load the data into SQL Server db if you do not know the structure of what is coming? How are you planing to use the data if the tables will change all the time?

Comment: The data will be used with a seperate frontend. I am not sure if you got me right. I wont drop anything from the source i just want to copy the whole structure to the sql server...

Comment: I did. I mean how will you use the data in any application? Unless it will be "select * from ..." you won't even be able to query the data and that screams of horrible design anyway. Normally you would create a staging database with all the data from the source system and push it to your OLTP database after matching the data structure. Can you distinguish any columns that do not change in the source?  Then in the future you could just add new columns if needed.

Comment: I know how horrible that sounds. The target application will track the changes and is made for it. I know the "normal" ETL way with all steps to SSAS so i can understand your displeasure. But i do not need to explain excactly why this is needed. Anyway i found a solution which works out quite well. I am not totally happy with it but i will rework that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution i got at the end:

1. Create a File/Table which is used for selection of the source tables.
2. Important: Create a linked Server on your SQL Instance or a working Connectionstring for the OPENROWSET (i was not able to do so - i choosed the linked server)
3. Query source File/Table
4. Build a loop through the resultset
5. Use Variables and Script Task to build your query
6. Drop the destination table
7. Build another Querystring with INSERT INTO TABLE FROM OPENROWSET (or if you used linked Server OPENQUERY)
8. Execute this Statement

Done. 
As i said above i am not quite happy with this but for now it should be ok. I will update this if i got another solution.